# Best way to pass across a list of parameters from one Controller to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my View I have a list of employees and a checkbox next to each one.
The user selects 1 or more employees and when he clicks submit, he navigates to the next page where he sees the details of each employee selected.
So I want to send a list of employee numbers from one controller to the next one.
One way I can do this is to use a Session object. But is that the best way?

Comment: This works out-of-the-box in ASP.NET MVC. Just emit a list of same-named checkboxes, and have the receiving action take an enumerable of IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think of this instead of having a view sending parameters to another controller.  in this case, from the employee list view to the details controller.  change the form on the list view such that it sends the selected employee ids to a method on the details controller.  in the details controller, you can query the database for whatever details you need for each of the given employee IDs

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. Views should not be making decisions on where they post back to. You'll run it to problems very quickly doing this. E.g Lets say the model is invalid. You will have to figure out where request came from and return the correct ViewResult.

Comment: sorry, i disagree.  this is the approach that the auto-gen code in visual studio takes

Comment: Lee has deleted his answer and I do not know why. I think your answer works and the question is whether it is good technique. I can see the logic in Lee's argument that it is not, but on the other hand if your solution is common practice then there are probably good arguments that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing employees you could POST a list of selected employee ids to the details controller and then fetch the corresponding details from your repository.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. By default, you can't pass a list/array from a POST to GET via a redirect.

Comment: Well, you could pass the ids as a comma separated parameter and then use a custom model binder or directly instruct the form to send a GET or POST request to the final action which will show the details. This way you don't need to redirect once again.